# Calling function from defined class in python?

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
import numpy as np

class Person:

    ...

    class Bob:

        def __init__(self, age, gender="Male"):

            self.age = age
            self.gender = gender

        def walk(x):

            return x / (180 * np.exp(-self.age / 35))

bob_1 = Person().Bob(37)
```

I want it to call the `walk(x)` function when calling `bob_1(x)` but still be able to call other methods as `bob_1.method(args)`.
Would Python happen to provide a way to do so?

Comment: It's not clear what you want.  You *can't* call `bob_1(x)` -- `bob_1` is an instance object, not a function.  You can call `bob_1.walk(100)`, for instance, but you *should* already know that from your tutorial on classes.

Comment: Ouch. Well, the question was whether there would be any way to make it behave in such a way that `bob_1(x)` would be valid. Which, as it turns out, does exist in the form of the `__call__()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining a class within a class makes the inner class count as a class-level variable, not an instance variable.

Doing this should work:

```
bob_1 = Person.Bob(37)   # note that we're not calling Person
print(bob_1.walk(30))
```

Note that `.walk()` is currently defined as a class method - to make it an instance method, you should define it as

```
def walk(self, x):
```

The `self` is passed implicitly when you call the method on an instance like `bob_1`.

---

If you want to have an instance display some behavior when you call it, then you can define the `__call__()` method on the class:

```
>>> class A:
...   def __call__(self, *args):
...     print(args)
... 
>>> g = A()
>>> g(3, 4, 5)
(3, 4, 5)
```

In your case, in order to make `bob_1(30)` behave like `bob_1.walk(30)`, you would do

```
def __call__(self, x):
    return self.walk(x)
```